# Как обернуть дивом несколько элементов без перечисления?

Tags: javascript

```
имею
<div id="slider2" class="slider1">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
         <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>

таких <div class="item"></div> более сотни

С помощью 

  $('.item').attr('id', function(index) { return (index + 1); })

задаю каждому **item** свой **id**

Вопрос
как мне обернуть в каждый свой див элементы 
с 1 по 5 (например)
с 6 по тридцатый 
с 31 по 60 
и так далее
60 -100

((так чтоб не перечислять id=1, id=2, id=3 и т.д.))
```

Comment: Нужно перебрать их

Comment: А БЕЗ перебора никак , у меня их более ста штук, как много когда будет, или я не о том ?

Comment: Вам нужно получить блок с элементами, перебрать его `nodeList`, видоизменив каждый из его элементов так, как вам угодно, то есть в вашем случае обернув в див.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, можно, например, так (группировка 1-5, 6-8, 9-10):

```js
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];
const sections = [[0, 5], [5, 8], [8, 10]];

sections.forEach((section, i) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = `div${i}`;
  document.body.append(div); // вставляете обёртку, куда вам нужно
  div.append(...items.slice(...section));
});
```

```html
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
<div class="item">10</div>
```

Comment: Ну так то оно так, новот блин чтото я совсем плохой, а как  чтобы эти дивы были со своими классами - чет у меня не получается.? ну что-то вроде ('<div class="new1 ">') далее ('<div class="new2">')

Comment: Вы про классы обёрток? А что мешает задать им классы через `div1.className = `?

Comment: Ну так то оно так, я добавляю div2.className = "new2 ";
div1.className = "new1 "; и так далее, я просто подумал что может быть изначально можно дивы задать с классами., потому как при разбиении на основного дива на пять частей это еще пять строк скрипта

Comment: А, вы хотите это всё сделать одним циклом. Вы ведь разбиваете 100 дивов не на равное количество элементов, у вас группы разного размера, как в примере из вопроса?

Comment: Еще одна штука вылезла, у меня в коде(ни здесь в примере, а на сайте )  вместо class="item"   я имею class="wow-item", и ввиду этого скрипт выдает ошибку, из-за черточки, как исправить этот момент ? я использовал $(".wow-item").addClass("item"); н о думаю есть другое решение..... как исправить?

Comment: Лучше вам об этом задать новый вопрос. Так что там с группами, они все разного размера?

Comment: Да разного , и много

Comment: Я отредактировал ответ. Вы можете создать массив с границами деления и затем перебрать эти границы в цикле, создавая группы и присваивая классы оберткам с номерами итераций. Если я правильно понял, что нужно. Только не запутайтесь с индексами массивов и параметрами slice.

Comment: это гениально ... но ка кэто оставить в пределах id="slider2" class="slider1

Comment: Не понимаю вопроса, простите)

Comment: у меня в условиях изначально и было написано имею
<div id="slider2" class="slider1">
        ..... это все нужно здесь и оставить
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>

Comment: заменил  document.body.append(div); //  НА slider2.append(div); // И ОСТАЮСЬ В ПРЕДЛАХ своего блока , правильно заменил?    https://jsfiddle.net/profy/xwosnjfu/198/

Comment: Думаю, правильно)